# Query too long with except

Tags: sql

Is there a shorter way ... ??

```
SELECT clid, cldoel, clanker, clprefix, clleerlijn, f1, f2, f3, f4 FROM Clusters  
WHERE clleerlijn like 'WJNLLUI%'   AND (f3 IS NOT NULL  OR f4 IS NOT NULL )
AND clid in(
Select agClid FROM agenda2 as a JOIN evaluaties2 as e ON a.agclid = e.evalclid and agLkrid = evallkrid 
WHERE (agSchoolid='18' and agDatum >=   '2013/01/01' and agDatum <=   '2013/02/12')
GROUP BY agClid
except
(SELECT agClid
FROM agenda2 as a 
    JOIN evaluaties2 as e 
        ON a.agclid = e.evalclid and agLkrid = evallkrid 
WHERE agSchoolid='18' 
    and agLkrid in (1,2932,2935) 
    and agDatum >= '2013/01/01' 
    and agDatum <= '2013/02/12' 
    AND evalWaarde = 3
GROUP BY agclid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT agLkrid) = 3)
)
```

Comment: Using joins instead of the subquery and `except` clause might make it shorter, but really what you have there isn't all that long.

Answer (score 0):

Only a little bit shorter, but better readable because of the same CTE being used twice:

```
WITH cte(clid) As (
  Select agClid FROM agenda2 as a JOIN evaluaties2 as e ON a.agclid = e.evalclid and agLkrid = evallkrid 
  WHERE (agSchoolid='18' and agDatum >= '2013/01/01' and agDatum <= '2013/02/12')
)
SELECT clid, cldoel, clanker, clprefix, clleerlijn, f1, f2, f3, f4 FROM Clusters  
WHERE clleerlijn like 'WJNLLUI%' AND (f3 IS NOT NULL  OR f4 IS NOT NULL )
AND clid in(
  SELECT DISTINCT agClid FROM cte
  except
  (SELECT agClid FROM cte WHERE agLkrid in (1,2932,2935) AND evalWaarde = 3
   GROUP BY agclid
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT agLkrid) = 3
  )
)
```

I also changed the first GROUP BY to a SELECT DISTINCT.

If you are looking for a more performant solution, this would be of no help. The rewritten SQL statement would not be evaluated faster.